# Dimissing TableViewController unwinds to first storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController.

When I click a button in my Detail View (Detail view is in a UITabViewController) to `showList` the UITableViewController (List Table View) called List is presented.
If I click the `Back` button in the navigation controller, I am taken back the ***correct*** screen: Detail View Shown by the Blue Line

If I select an list item the delegate method `didSelectFromList` is called from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and the app is taken back to main screen (Home View) shown by 
the red line.

What I want is the purple line.

[image]

Any help?

**Attempt 1:**

I let the delegate dismiss the List TableVC.

```
#import "ListTableViewController.h"
@interface CallDetailViewController () <ListTableViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) LotListTableViewController * lltvc;
@end


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_list"]) {
        self.lltvc = (ListTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        self.lltvc.delegate = self;
    }

}

- (void) showList {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_list" sender:self];
}

#pragma mark LIST SELECTION DELEGATE METHOD

- (void) didSelectFromList:(NSString *)item {
    [self.lltvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Did Select item:  %@", item);
    }];
}
```

**In the LIST TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   ///.. stuff to find the correct string

   [self.delegate didSelectFromList:item];


}
```

**Attempt 2:**

Here I let the List TableVC dimiss itself.

```
#import "ListTableViewController.h"
@interface CallDetailViewController () <ListTableViewControllerDelegate>

@end


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_lots"]) {
        NSLog(@"GOING TO THE LOT LIST");

        UINavigationController * nvc = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        LotListTableViewController *lltvc = [nvc childViewControllers][0];
        lltvc.delegate = self;

    }

}

- (void) showLotList {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_lots" sender:self];

}
#pragma mark LIST SELECTION DELEGATE METHOD

- (void) didSelectFromList:(NSString *)item {
       NSLog(@"Did Select item:  %@", item);

}
```

**In the LIST TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   ///.. stuff to find the correct string

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.delegate didSelectFromList:item];

    }];
}
```

I have also tried from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the List TableVC

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.delegate didSelectFromList:item];

    }];
```

Comment: Instead of pushing the nav controller from detailVC, present the nav controller  that has the list table VC. In that case [self.nav dismissviewCOntroller will work,

Comment: That's the correct answer. I was Pushing the List instead of Presenting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep on pushing view controller, they get added to the navigation stack, so if you do [self dismiss or [self.navigationController dismiss, all the navigation stack is cleared and you will betaken to the rootViewController.

Either you can pop one view controller or 
Instead of pushing the navigation controller from detailVC, present the navigation controller that has the list table VC. In that case `[self.nav dismissviewCOntroller` will work,